# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1

Tags: java, arraylist

I obtained this exception when I execute this code?Any help please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    professeur f = new professeur();
    ArrayList<Integer> arl =new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int  k=0;
    etudiant e = new etudiant();
    List<etudiant> list = e.getAll();
    List<professeur> l = f.getAll1();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).getIde()==l.get(i).getIdp())  {
                 k=list.get(i).getIde();

                System.out.println(list.get(i).getNome());
            } 
           break;


        }

           professeur p=new professeur();
           List <professeur> c= p.findAllbyID(k);
           System.out.println(c.get(i).getNomp());}



    }

}
```

Comment: Help in advice: learn how to use debugger!

Comment: Comment on code style: the naming of your variables is **very** confusing. You create an Object of class "professeur" (class names should start with upper case btw). And then this class "professur" has a method `getAll1()` that is supposed to return ... a list of professeurs? That sounds extremely strange. First of all, the method name should say something about what it will do, like "getAssociatedProfesseurs" or something like that. And of course; from an OO point of view; it simply feels wrong that a single professor provides a method to return more professors.

Comment: Coding style continued: use the "foreach" syntax for iterating lists, like `for (Etudiant etudiant : e.getAll())` (where I "fixed" the classname to start upper case) That is **much** easier to write, read, and maintain than C-style for loops.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you got your indices switched.

Since `i` iterates over the indices of `list` and `j` iterates over the indices of `l`, it should be :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < l.size(); j++) {
        if (list.get(i).getIde()==l.get(j).getIdp())  { // i and j were switched
                                                        // on this line
             k=list.get(i).getIde();

            System.out.println(list.get(i).getNome());
        } 
       break;


    }
```

Comment: yes ,but also exception  : Exception in thread “main” java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2,  Size: 2

Comment: @user3491229 You are probably getting the exception in a different place now. I'm guessing at `c.get(i).getNomp()`. You can't be sure that the `c` List has as many elements as the `list` List, so calling `c.get(i)` is not safe.